# How can i check if a folder auto mounted on NFS share?

Tags: linux, mount, nfs, automounting

There are a folder /collect, i want to determine if this folder are auto mounted on NFS share.

I got a method or tips like: "ls /collect" use "mount" to check if /collect on h%svcnfs1:/export/shared/collect Expected Result: /collect folder can be automounted on NFS share And i don't know how can i use "mount" to check it, or is there are specific command relevant "mount" ?

Comment: What are you asking, and what have you tried?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add further information. Don't add it in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

NFS Share:::    h%svcnfs1:/export/shared/collect
Mount point:::   /collect

If you want to check whether this NFS share is mounted or not, use "df -h" command to check

in case if this file system is not mounted upon a reboot then you need to add this device entry in /etc/fstab.

Hope this helps..